# C# WinForms add controls programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Can someone suggest the best way to achieve my goal?

So, I have a form with three buttons. What I want is, depending on what button is pressed on panel should be shown different controls (user control). I made this in a simple way: all are added from the beginning, I just make change to the visibility. But what would be nice is, if someone can suggest a more appropriate way, because there is no need to have objects created from beginning.

Comment: Try using `asp:UpdatePanel`: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Comment: @markzzz For Windows Forms?

Comment: What have you tried?  You really should post your code; it's hard to suggest changes without seeing _what you have already done_.

Comment: pfff... I read WebForms sorry ;) It is late!

Comment: in your case it's better to have them "from beginning"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always create the appropriate `UserControl`, and add it to the [Panel.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) at runtime.  This will allow you to create the control(s) as needed, instead of on initialization of your Form.

Comment: It's certainly possible, however I would suggest that it makes it harder to design and a little more complicated.  Better to have them all there and simply show/hide based on input.

Comment: @Liath It really depends - if the user controls have long initialization, creating 3 up front can create UI hiccups.  Sometimes lazy loading IS very appropriate - but it really depends on the scenario.

Comment: @Liath That is a very bad idea as the controls would overlap with each other at design time and every control would be loaded in memory which don't need to be.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - I'd go with that.  Depends on the situation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed create the controls at design time - if there's advantage no to dynamically create them.  Why complicate matters?

If there are a number of controls I would put them all in a panel (within the panel you've already mentioned) so you're only changing the visibility of a single control (the panel) rather than each one within it.

When you press the appropriate button show the appropriate panel (and remember to hide the others in case you've previously shown them)

Comment: I agree - unless the controls have long initialization times, in which case creating 3 may be slower than necessary (ie: creating a UI hiccup)